# Oracle Apex Checkbox on Interactive Report

Tags: oracle, oracle-apex

I have an Interactive Report with the following column for a checkbox:

```
apex_item.hidden(01, my_table_id)||apex_item.checkbox2(02, my_table_id)
```

And with that, I have a process that updates data on my_table based on what checkbox (my_table_id) is selected.
Now, that button can only be enabled if the user checks on one of this checkboxes.
Is there a way to know the value of these report checkboxes in order to create a Dynamic Action?
(I know that the value of each checkbox is my_table_id value, but since this is always unique (and I have thousands of rows), was wondering if there's something to be done about it)

Thanks

Comment: Can the user check one checkbox or more, or do you just want a DA to enable the button as soon as any row is checked ? If all checkboxes are unchecked, should the button be disabled again ?

Comment: Thank you, the user can select one or more yes. The idea is for the button (with the DA) to be enabled if the user selects at least one checkbox. Disable if there are no checkboxes selected. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not as simple as enabling/disabling a button based on a check. Once more than one button is checked and the user unchecks you need through loop through all rows to check if any others are checked. The best way is a technique to keep track of all checked ids and update whenever a box is checked/unchecked.

Then you can create an additional dynamic action to disable the button if no checkboxes are checked.

There are a couple of blogs that explain the top how to do what described at the top - it's best that you read through them and create a solution based on the one you think suits you best.
https://hardlikesoftware.com/weblog/2015/07/24/apex-interactive-report-checkbox-row-selection/
http://apex-smb.blogspot.com/2015/09/report-with-checkboxes-update.html